# ReSet all password status to zero using trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am optimizing my login system in which I am maintain previous passwords of a user, schema of **pwd** table for maintaining passwords is as follows:

[image: Password table schema]

here userId refers to primary key of  user table. 
If **status** attribute is 1 that means row has marking current password if it is 0 previous password.

How can I write a trigger so that if a new entry for any user is made in **pwd**
table, all previous status of that user gets set to 0 and new value will remain 1 as the default value of **status** attribute. Currently I am doing so at application level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't be possible because it would require to have a mutating (changing the same table it's being fired upon) trigger which is prohibited in MySQL.

You can create a stored procedure though, but you would still need to call it from the client code explicitly.

Now a better schema design would be to keep all current passwords in one table (presumably in the `users` table) and all previous in the other (i.e. `pwd_history`). Not only it makes queries for current passwords faster it also allows you to use a trigger if you choose to.

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER tg_pwd_history 
AFTER UPDATE ON users
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NOT NEW.pwd <=> OLD.pwd THEN
    INSERT INTO pwd_history (`userId`, `pwd`, `ts`)
    VALUES (NEW.id, OLD.pwd, NOW());
  END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2252a/1)** demo

Now I very much hope you're not storing them in plain text.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem and yes I am not storing passwords in plain text.